# C++ cannot convert unsigned char to char* when calling my function

Tags: c++

In this program I use the function [gethostname](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB23S_1.1.0.7/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.07/gtpc2/cpp_gethostname.html) to get the hostname of the server. However when running this below:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
⋮
int  rc;
int  server_sock;
u_char hostname[50];
⋮
rc = gethostname(&hostname,sizeof(hostname));
printf("hostname = %s\n",hostname);
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot convert u_char(*)[50] to char* for argument '1' to 'int gethostname(char*, size_t)'
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(hostname)`

Comment: [MCVE] please, as usual.

Comment: The vertical ellipsis is very inventive, but it is no more of a substitute for a proper MCVE than is "`// some code here`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of the wrong type (`u_char` instead of `char`) and you're passing a pointer to the array rather than passing it directly - `&hostname` is of type `u_char(*)[50]` - you want just a pointer, which would be just `hostname`:

The correct approach would be:

```
char hostname[50];
⋮
rc = gethostname(hostname,sizeof(hostname));
```